# Узнать, из определённой страны посетитель, или нет

Tags: php

Я бы хотел на сайте узнать, пришел ли посетитель из определённой, или из любой другой страны. Я поискал и нашел решения искать по мировой базе IP.

Но это как-то слишком, мне кажется. Мне не нужны все страны, мне просто нужно знать, из определённой страны человек, или нет.

Можно как-то это сделать малой кровью?

Comment: Если без шуток: уточните, какой информацией вы располагаете? Почему вам не подходит вариант поискать по мировой базе и определить "Украина/не Украина"? Возможно, стоит копать в сторону определения подмножества IP из Украины и просто хранить эту информацию. (Впрочем, я не уверен, насколько часто такая информация меняется). А ещё у вас будут пользователи под TOR, которые на самом деле из Украины, но заходят через Тьмутаракань.

Comment: можно воспользоваться сервисами вида https://ipinfo.io/ и не забывать кешировать запросы.

Comment: Вариант смотреть заголовок запроса "Accept-Language" на наличие там Украинского языка.

Comment: Accept-Language, кстати, подходит - спасибо! Не подумал про него.

Answer (score 1):

Скачиваешь дамп айпишников 
https://sypexgeo.net/ru/download/

подключаешь , и можешь по любому IP - узнать любую страну и любой город, и без коннектов во время определения на сторонние сайты !

Answer (score 0):

Вот пример моей реализации с помощью wipmania

```
function geoBlocking(){
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']))
{
    $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
}
elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))
{
    $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
} else {
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
}
$server = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$country = file_get_contents('http://api.wipmania.com/'.$ip.'?'.$server.'');
$validate = 'US';
if($validate !== $country){
    //code
}
 else {
    header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].' 400 Bad Request');
    exit('you country is blocked');
}
}
```

Comment: Отличное решение. Только я считаю, что нужно сделать 20-30 проверок в цикле к нескольким сервисам, чтобы наверняка.

Comment: Ну сделал 20 запросов, все сказали разный результат. И что дальше? Плюс есть спорные территории, как в них определять?

Comment: @KoVadim:  Нужно отдельные таблицы адресов спорных территорий, разумеется. Если сервис не предоставляет их — это плохой сервис.

Comment: сервис может не считать спорную территорию таковой. Более того, айпишники могут мигрировать и мои знакомые попали в такую ситуацию. (большая компания перенесла часть свох айпи с одной страны в другую). Как результат, они были забанены в гугле (да, такое бывает).

Но есть ещё лучше ситуация. У меня на телефоне, когда заходишь на сайт моего оператора через 3г неверно определяется область.

Вывод - вычислять по айпи нужно осторожно.